# Error while installing chatterbot using pip. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, pip, chatterbot

Following is the error after trying to pip install Chatterbot. 
Operating System: Windows 11 
Python Version: 3.10.0 
Pip Version: 23.3.1

```
pip install chatterbot
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached Pint-0.23-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.1 kB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached pymongo-3.13.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (394 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
        Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
      Collecting Cython
        Using cached Cython-3.0.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
        Using cached cymem-2.0.8-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
      Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
        Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      ERROR: Some build dependencies for preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz conflict with the backend dependencies: wheel==0.42.0 is incompatible with wheel>=0.32.0,<0.33.0.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.`enter code here`
```

Troubleshooting Steps Attempted:
I tried upgrading the wheel package using pip install --upgrade wheel. 
I attempted to install specific versions of conflicting packages using pip install wheel==0.32.3, pip install preshed==2.0.1, and pip install chatterbot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of ChatterBot (1.0.8) currently supports python versions 3.4 - 3.8. You are having this issue because your Python Version is 3.10.0 hence it's not supported by ChatterBot 1.0.8. To fix this, downgrade your python version to any of the supported versions. Visit https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I use Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook. Try to create a new environment in Anaconda Navigator and choose to install Python version 3.7.16.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35727040)